# How to tell if a usb mass storage device is plugged in using dbus

Tags: python, dbus

I am working on making a simple python program to mount and unmount flash drives so that I don't have to do more than just look at a list and choose what I want to mount. Right now, I have a list of objects and properties for each device. What I want to know is which properties I should look at to tell if a device is a usb mass storage device. My first instinct is to look at 'Detachable', however I only have one device plugged in (my kindle) but I'm getting two detachable devices. The two properties that I'm noticing are different are that /dev/sdb has a blank 'IdLabel' and 'IdUsage'. This is the code that I have right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dbus

def get_devices():
  bus = dbus.SystemBus()
  ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks',
                                  '/org/freedesktop/UDisks')
  ud_manager = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks')

  proplist = []

  for device in ud_manager.EnumerateDevices():
    device_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks', device)
    device_props = dbus.Interface(device_obj, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
    proplist.append(device_props.GetAll('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device'))

  for device_props in proplist:
    print '----------'
    print device_props['IdLabel']
    print device_props['DeviceFile']
    print device_props['IdUsage']
    if device_props['DriveCanDetach']:
      print 'Device is detachable'
    else:
      print 'Device is not detachable'

get_devices()
```

And the two outputs I'm talking about are:

```
Kindle
/dev/sdb1
filesystem
Device is detachable
----------

/dev/sdb

Device is detachable
```

Result of udisks --show-info /dev/sdb1

```
Showing information for /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb1
  native-path:                 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-1/3
-1:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1                                           
  device:                      8:17
  device-file:                 /dev/sdb1
    presentation:              /dev/sdb1
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kindle_Internal_Storage_90D42204345600JR
-0:0-part1                                                                                
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-uuid/386D-5422
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:04:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-
part1                                                                                     
  detected at:                 Sat 04 Jan 2014 03:56:35 PM EST
  system internal:             0
  removable:                   0
  has media:                   1 (detected at Sat 04 Jan 2014 03:56:35 PM EST)
    detects change:            0
    detection by polling:      0
    detection inhibitable:     0
    detection inhibited:       0
  is read only:                0
  is mounted:                  0
  mount paths:             
  mounted by uid:              0
  presentation hide:           0
  presentation nopolicy:       0
  presentation name:           
  presentation icon:           multimedia-player
  automount hint:              
  size:                        1432346624
  block size:                  512
  job underway:                no
  usage:                       filesystem
  type:                        vfat
  version:                     FAT32
  uuid:                        386D-5422
  label:                       Kindle
  partition:
    part of:                   /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb
    scheme:                    mbr
    number:                    1
    type:                      0x0b
    flags:                    
    offset:                    8192
    alignment offset:          0
    size:                      1432346624
    label:                     
    uuid:
```

Result of udisks --show-info /dev/sdb

```
Showing information for /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb
  native-path:                 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0/usb3/3-1/3
-1:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb                                                
  device:                      8:16
  device-file:                 /dev/sdb
    presentation:              /dev/sdb
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kindle_Internal_Storage_90D42204345600JR
-0:0                                                                                      
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:04:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
  detected at:                 Sat 04 Jan 2014 03:56:34 PM EST
  system internal:             0
  removable:                   1
  has media:                   1 (detected at Sat 04 Jan 2014 03:56:34 PM EST)
    detects change:            1
    detection by polling:      1
    detection inhibitable:     1
    detection inhibited:       0
  is read only:                0
  is mounted:                  0
  mount paths:             
  mounted by uid:              0
  presentation hide:           0
  presentation nopolicy:       0
  presentation name:           
  presentation icon:           multimedia-player
  automount hint:              
  size:                        1432354816
  block size:                  512
  job underway:                no
  usage:                       
  type:                        
  version:                     
  uuid:                        
  label:                       
  partition table:
    scheme:                    mbr
    count:                     1
  drive:
    vendor:                    Kindle
    model:                     Internal Storage
    revision:                  0100
    serial:                    90D42204345600JR
    WWN:                       
    detachable:                1
    can spindown:              0
    rotational media:          Yes, unknown rate
    write-cache:               unknown
    ejectable:                 0
    adapter:                   Unknown
    ports:
    similar devices:
    media:                     
      compat:                 
    interface:                 usb
    if speed:                  480000000 bits/s
    ATA SMART:                 not available
```

So what I would like to know if checking that there is an IdLabel and IdUsage are enough to assume something is a USB mass storage device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could go with UDisks2 DBus interface the answer would be quite simple :-)
First of all, it seems that UDisks2 (and probably UDisks1, but I haven't it installed) handles only Mass Storage devices connected via USB, completely ignoring USB-connected MTP-devices and other kinds of USB devices such as printers and mice. Have a look:

Right now I have 6 USB devices connected:

```
alex@galene ~ $ /usr/sbin/lsusb | grep -v 'root hub'
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:000a A4 Tech Co., Ltd Optical Mouse Opto 510D
Bus 008 Device 090: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Bus 008 Device 075: ID 04b8:0007 Seiko Epson Corp. Printer
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 009 Device 088: ID 1058:1010 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements External HDD
```

058f:6362 is an "all-in one" card reader w/ a SD-card currently plugged in.
058f:6387 and 1058:1010 are real USB Mass Storage devs, a flash and an external HDD respectively. 04e8:6860 is a Samsung Galaxy Note1 (an MTP-device) and the rest are the mouse and the printer.

Also I have an internal SATA drive.

Here's the current `udisksctl status` output (as you may see Galaxy Note is missing):

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hitachi HDT725040VLA360   V5COA7EA  VFM301R3196R5F       sda     
Generic Flash Disk        8.07      8D0147DF             sdb     
WDC WD1200BEVS-22RST0     04.01G04  WD-WXE108V72690      sdc     
Generic USB CF Reader     1.01      058F312D81B          sde     
Generic USB SM Reader     1.02      058F312D81B          sdf     
Generic USB MS Reader     1.03      058F312D81B          sdg     
Generic USB SD Reader     1.00      058F312D81B          sdd
```

To distinguish pluggable USB Mass storage devices from stationary drives one may check
'ConnectedBus' and ''Removable' properties. Please note that there's another property 'MediaRemovable' which corresponds to the physical media of the device. Here's the script which selects removable USB Mass Storage devices and prints their 'MediaRemovable' property

```
alex@galene ~ $ cat <<EOF | python -
> import dbus
> bus = dbus.SystemBus()
> ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
> om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
> for k,v in om.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
>     drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive', {})
>     if drive_info.get('ConnectionBus') == 'usb' and drive_info.get('Removable'):
>         print("Device Path: %s, MediaRemovable: %s" % (k, drive_info['MediaRemovable']))
> block_devices =  [''.join(chr(c) for c in device[dbus.String(u'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block')][dbus.String(u'PreferredDev‌​ice')] if chr(c) != '\x00' ) for device in om.GetManagerObjects().values() if dbus.String(u'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block') in device]
> EOF
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Generic_USB_SM_Reader_058F312D81B, MediaRemovable: 1
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Generic_Flash_Disk_8D0147DF, MediaRemovable: 1
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Generic_USB_SD_Reader_058F312D81B, MediaRemovable: 1
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD1200BEVS_22RST0_WD_WXE108V72690, MediaRemovable: 0
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Generic_USB_CF_Reader_058F312D81B, MediaRemovable: 1
Device Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Generic_USB_MS_Reader_058F312D81B, MediaRemovable: 1
```

Basically it solves the problem you're trying to solve. Rumors say that there're *non-removable* USB-connected storage devices but I haven't seen such.

Comment: I know that it is older question. But udisks2 drives me grazy.  Is it possible to list all USB devies in this format  `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sdd1` and so on?

Comment: Without filtering pluggable/non-pluggable etc the command looks like this: `[''.join(chr(c) for c in device[dbus.String(u'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block')][dbus.String(u'PreferredDevice')] if chr(c) != '\x00' ) for device in om.GetManagerObjects().values() if dbus.String(u'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block') in device]`. `om` is defined in the code snippet above.

Comment: Can you edit and your answer. I do not know where to insert the above code.

Comment: Check `block_devices` definition

Comment: I ended up using this code `bus = dbus.SystemBus()
ud_manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UDisks2', '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2')
om = dbus.Interface(ud_manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
for k,v in om.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
  drive_info = v.get('org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block', {})
  if drive_info.get('IdUsage') == "filesystem" and not drive_info.get('HintSystem'):
 print "/dev/" + k[-5:]`   I am sure that it is not the elegant code. But it works.

Comment: Technically, it's not completely correct, but if it works for you, I don't see any reason to argue.

Comment: :-)). Not elegent because the doc says that `System devices are devices that require additional permissions to access.` There could be possibility that other internal hard drives may get listed. Ok comming to the code you you provided, I get the this error `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'GetManagerObjects'` only only workable solution using udisks2, pyhton and dbus is yours (google says so). So please bear with me.

Comment: Mean while, I tried agin using the slightly modified code found on the calibre software https://gist.github.com/mbusb/f674183c169e431c356e  It actally returns all device block files like "/dev/sda1" , "/devsdb1" and so on. I do not know how to filter this list in to USB drives only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51735/discussion-between-user3159253-and-sundar-ima)